# Python Scraping HTML table based on column names

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm not sure if i'm even on the right path with this question, but I couldn't find any resources to help me.

I've developed the beginning of a scraper that walks through this list of links (https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Trainer_classes) and goes to each trainer class page.  I want to scrape the contents of certain tables in each trainer class's page.  The part i'm having trouble with is building code dynamic enough to work with all the links i'm walking through.

XPath isn't really an option, since ALL of the tables (including the ones I don't want) on the page have an Xpath like this:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[6]
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[7]
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[4]
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[3]
```

There isn't a consistent table number that the tables I want begin at.  So, in reality my question becomes...

How do I scrape all tables that have the column names TrainerName/Battle/Winnings/Pokemon?  I couldn't find any resources that walked me though scraping tables based on the text contents of their  tag?

Here's an example of a page I would be trying to scrape:

https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ace_Duo_(Trainer_class)

Maybe I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way, but this was the best idea I could come up with.  Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is another Python library you can use for extracting data from HTML and XML documents.

Comment: I was planning on using beautiful soup to parse the html, but it still wasn't leading me in the right direction.  The end goal is scraping a table based off of column names in a table.  Could you show an example of how that might work with beautifulsoup, please?